# Problems accessing data from jQuery “serialize()” form to PHP backend

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, serialization

I’m trying to pass values from a dynamic form to PHP, using [jQuery `serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/), but I am only receiving part of the string:

The form is created by a MySQL query:

```
echo '<form role="form" id="reserva_tour" action="shop_wopt.php" method="POST">';
 $db->Consultar("SELECT * FROM tour_options WHERE tourID = '$tour_id' order by tourID");    
while($row = $db->ObtenerArray()) {
    $regis   = $row['recid'];
    $name    = $row['name'];
    $radl    = $row['adl_rate'];
    print "<a href='#' class='tit_tour btn btn-success'>$name - $$ratebase</a>";
    print "<input type='text' name='open_adl[$regis]' id='adl$regis'  class='adl' />";
  }
  print "<a href='#' class='calcTourOpt btn btn-block">Tour Calc </a>";
  print "</form>";
```

The jQuery:

```
$(".calcTourOpt").click(function()
  {
      var adl = $('.adl').serialize().replace(/%5B/g, '[').replace(/%5D/g, ']');
      console.log(adl);
      $.ajax({
         url: "calctour_opt.php",
         data:"adl=" + adl + "", 
         type: "POST",
         dataType: "json",
         cache: false,
         success: function(data){
            console.log(data)
         }  
      });
    });
```

This is `calctour_opt.php`:

```
$adl   = $_POST['adl'];
$values = array();
parse_str($adl);   
$total = $open_adl[4]; 
echo json_encode($total);
```

This is happening:

After serializing the class "adl" (before the ajax call, in the console.log), the string looks  like this: `open_adl[4]=2&open_adl[5]=3`   and is correct!

In my php file if I declare `$total = $open_adl[4];` works fine, it shows me the result: `2`.

But if I change to: `$total = $open_adl[5];` does not work, it shows me `NULL`, instead of `3`.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Another silly question: How can I run print_r($open_adl) on the Ajax Call. As you see I'm sending the form to Jquery, then I made the Ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change $.ajax `data` param  from `string` to `json` string like this

```
// FROM 
$.ajax({
     url: "calctour_opt.php",
     data:"adl=" + adl + "", //<- Wrong
     type: "POST",
     ...

// TO
$.ajax({
     url: "calctour_opt.php",
     data: {adl: adl}, //<- Correct
```

check documentation here about `data` param for ajax - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I'm sending the Form Input to Jquery as class 'adl'  $('.adl') and then I made the ajax call with variable adl  data:"adl=" + adl + ""